# How to check variable and/or array values in node.js command prompt

Tags: node.js

I just started learning Node.js and I have the following question:

Is there an easy way to check variable, array, etc., values in the node.js command prompt or shell? For example, when writing normal javascript, I am used to opening up the browser's console where I can just type in the name of a variable to see its value.

How would I do this same thing when writing code in node.js? I know I can open the shell and write javascript, and then type in variable names and it will return their values, but how can I do this on the fly, as I'm writing an app?

Comment: What do you mean by _on the fly_ ?

Comment: Let me explain a real-world example, and maybe it will make more sense. I have an app that uses a variable that I call index, which starts out at 0 (var index = 0). When the user clicks an arrow on an html page, this index increases by 1. I can check this value 'on the fly' by opening up the browser's console and just typing 'index.' Then, when I click the arrow twice, I type 'index' and it returns '2.' This helps me see that everything is working as I expect. In the node.js command prompt, I can't just type 'index' to see its value...is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've figured this out...

Just as in front-end javascript development, you can input 'debugger;' into your .js file where you want to begin debugging. Then, from your command prompt, you would type:

node --inspect-brk [filename] [anything else required to call the function]

After this, open a tab in Chrome and type 'chrome://inspect' You should then see a link that reads 'Open dedicated DevTools for Node.' When you click this, you will be able to debug the program from Chrome, just as you normally would when working on browser-based programs. This works with nodemon as well, and you can leave this window open while working, no need to close/open for different files, etc.

Hope this helps someone else who is also new to Node!